# Keras dot product layer by last axis

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have Siamese network that produce feature maps for images, how do I get dot product of those feature maps with Keras?

```
input_a = Input(input_size)
input_b = Input(input_size)
fe_net_a = model(input_a)
fe_net_b = model(input_b)
```

E.g. if output tensor of `fe_net_a` and `fe_net_b` has shape (1, 17, 17, 1024), how to create layer that will produce tensor of shape (1, 17, 17), taking dot product of last axis?

Answer (score 0):

From the keras documentation of [the `merge.Dot()` function](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot_1), is  this what you are looking for?

```
from keras.layers import Input, dot

input_a = Input(input_size)
input_b = Input(input_size)
fe_net_a = model(input_a)
fe_net_b = model(input_b)

fe_ab = dot([fe_net_a,fe_net_b], axes = -1)
```

Does that work for you ?

Comment: Nope, it produces tensor of shape (1, 17, 17, 17). I'm new to Keras and deep learning, so I don't know why it's doing that.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. Please give us some reproducible code :)

Comment: ```>>> input_size=20, 10, 3
>>> input_a = Input(input_size)
>>> input_b = Input(input_size)
>>> fe_ab = dot([input_a, input_b], axes=-1)
>>> fe_ab
<tf.Tensor 'dot_2/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 20, 10, 10) dtype=float32>```